# xCode 6 how to fix "Use of undeclared identifier" for automatic property synthesis?

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, xcode6, automatic-properties

I'm using xCode6 Beta 3, and am running into an issue where a code which previously compiled fine (xCode 5.1.1 or xCode6 beta 2) suddenly started to give me **"Use of undeclared identifier"** errors when accessing an automatically synthesized instance variable:

```
- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _finished = finished;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

//ERROR:
 Use of undeclared identifier '_finished'; did you mean 'finished'?
```

Adding `@synthesize finished = _finished;` makes the error go away, but **is there a way to force xCode6 Beta 3 to use automatic property synthesis using underscore notation?**

Comment: Do you also have an explicit getter method? If so, the ivar won't be auto synthesized for you any more.

Comment: Yup, you need `@synthesize finished = _finished;` if you have both the getter and setter.  This happens in earlier versions of Xcode too.

Comment: Found the same problem in SDWebImage - Toolkit.. You gave already the answer: manually add a @synthesize statement - or wait until release of xcode.

Comment: @jeffamaphone this does not happens in earlier versions of xcode, OP probably has this error from the MWPhotoBrowser library, it used to work and compile perfectly in xcode 5, installed xcode 6 and suddenly got this error too.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

At first I thought it was a beta version bug, but today I saw that this type of errors occur on the XCode 6 GM Seed also, though I'm yet to discover in which particular cases.

Anyway, the fix is to add a synthesize statement in the @implementation block, explicitly declaring the name of the ivar as well as the property:

```
@synthesize property = _property
```

Comment: what to do if it is in Pods library

Comment: File a bug.  Or fix it and send the pod owner a PR.  Or branch it.

Comment: I just had issues with CocoaPods (SDWebImageDownloaderOperation) and adding the synthesize calls solved everything!!! Thanks "drowntoge"

Comment: Ran into this issue on Xcode 6.1.1, only solution was to synthesize manually.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an explicit **getter**, **automatic property synthesized** will be **ignored**.

Then you have to use `@synthesize property = _property`

Answer (score 3):

pod update

then your can now update to 3.7.1 that has fixed this bug.