# trouble building MKStoreKit with Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkstorekit

Our app uses MKStoreKit for in-app purchases. We recently updated everything to iOS8 but we are having trouble building MKStoreKit with Xcode 6.

The file that is having trouble is `VerificationController.m`. We have the latest version from github. The build errors are in `checkReceiptSecurity`. `Use of Undeclared Identifier ‘outLabel’`

That same function also complains about `encodeBase64` and `decodeBase64`.

Answer (score 0):

See this question for the solution of the "use of undeclared identifier" errors in Xcode 6:

[xCode 6 how to fix "Use of undeclared identifier" for automatic property synthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638826/xcode-6-how-to-fix-use-of-undeclared-identifier-for-automatic-property-synthes/25762104#25762104)

Comment: Thank for your answer, downtoge. it works for me. Moreover, i also found some mistakes when i mix oc and c programing and i fix them. it can build without no errors now.