# Error on overriding setter/getter of property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, setter, getter

I'm having a strange error when trying to override the `setter` and `getter` of a property.

On my header file I've defined the following property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *startedOn;
```

On the implementation, I have this `setter`:

```
- (NSDate *)startedOn {
    if (!_startedOn) {
        [self updateStartedOn];
    }

    return _startedOn;
}
```

Everything is working as it should at this point, but, when I try to override the `setter` like this:

```
- (void)setStartedOn:(NSDate *)startedOn {
    _startedOn = startedOn;
}
```

I get the following error:

[image]

This doesn't make any sense to me, what I've checked:

- The setter nor getter have any duplicated definition
- The parent class doesn't have any duplicated definition
- None of the class's categories have any duplicated definition

Does any one have a clue of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You can also read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817562/property-not-working-with-getter-and-setter and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638826/xcode-6-how-to-fix-use-of-undeclared-identifier-for-automatic-property-synthes there are many more threads about this. Make sure you search before creating a new :) GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put in the implementation file;

```
@synthesize startedOn = _startedOn;
```